# Sticky header logo css

Tags: css, header, sticky

I have a sticky header on my website (wesurf.co.il), but the logo somehow got placed below the sticky header menu, while I want it to be on the left. I tried to search for css codes for the logo line but couldn't find. 
Thanks for helping

also - it seems that if I change something in position of my original logo it also changes the sticky header logo, how do i fix that?

this is my header in style.css

```html
/* = Header
----------------------------------------------- */
#header .logo {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#header .nav-main {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#header .nav-main.boxed {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}
.sticky-header {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.98;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 9998;
}
.sticky-header:before,
.sticky-header:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
.sticky-header:after {
  clear: both;
}
.sticky-header .logo {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 70px;
  padding: 17px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.sticky-header .nav-main {
  float: right;
}
.sticky-header .sf-menu > li > a {
  line-height: 60px !important;
  padding: 0;
}
.sticky-header .sf-menu > li:hover > ul,
.sticky-header .sf-menu > li.sfHover > ul {
  top: 60px;
}
.sticky-header .sf-menu > li:last-child > a {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.sticky-header .menu-no-found {
  line-height: 70px;
}
body.admin-bar .sticky-header {
  top: 32px !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hey Paulie, what I posted is ok?

Comment: Not really. PHP can't reproduce the issue. We need the **minimum amount of *output* HTML & CSS** to show the problem.

Comment: I added the header part in my Style.Css, I dont know how to find the equivalent for html for that part. is that enough though?

Answer (score 0):

try this

say your logo has class logo

```
.logo{
position:relative;
left:15px//adjust accordingly
}
```

Comment: This also effect my original logo, I only want to change the logo that inside the sticky header